# Is it possible to construct a working Facebook "Like" button using your own graphics?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Google is failing me here.  I have a designer who needs desperately to have a like button that is not delivered from Facebook's iframe code and uses her graphics.

Anyone seen an example of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is against FaceBook Rules to do this.

Based on the [policy here](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php), since the 'Like' Button is explicitly displayed on that page. And under the 'Like' Button item 3 reads:

> While you may scale the size to suit
>   your needs, you may not modify the
>   Like Button in any other way (such as
>   by changing the design)

But based on [this discussion](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=81844) it may or may not be ok, depending on how big you are. [This article](http://www.esrun.co.uk/blog/disguising-a-facebook-like-link/) shows you how, but beware facebook may get you for not using it correctly.